# how to get cell tower id from dual sim2

Tags: android, location, telephonymanager, dual-sim, cellid

i can get first sim cell tower id with this below code. but i want to get second sim2 cell id.

```
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
  int   nowcid  = cellLocation.getCid();
  int nowlac = cellLocation.getLac();
```

there is many questions about this. but i tested all codes with android 6.0 samsung j7 2016 but didnt got the sim2 cell id. 
some people say this is impossible on other questions but Network Cell Info Lite 
app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wilysis.cellinfolite&hl=en  gets cell id from sim2 on every device i tested.

Comment: Any fixes for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For MediaTek devices there is the hidden class
`com.mediatek.telephony.TelephonyManagerEx`. Use reflection to access this class. This should work reliable on MTK devices. The simId paramater used has for SIM 0 value 0 and for SIM 2 value 1.

Study the very hard to find API description: http://www.lcis.com.tw/paper_store/ps_html/MediaTek_SDK_for_Android_Developers_Guide_v1_0-2016103002732388.pdf.html

There is a static `getDefault`method.

For Qualcomm based phones there are hidden methods in the TelephonyManager. Just `TelephonyManager.class.getDeclaredMethods()` inside the debugger to see what is available.